# Do I need to be worried about selling quest-crucial items?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I was going through my inventory to sell to a merchant and ran across some items that sound like they might have been quest related items, but I don't remember: People's Journals, Warsworn Ranks, Graveside Letter, etc.

Do I need to be worried about potentially selling something that I would need to complete a quest?

Comment: You should actually worry about the opposite - I finished the game with several items stuck in my inventory that could not be dropped, junked, or sold because they were for quests that I'd already completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The game will not allow you to sell or junk quest related items and they will not take up inventory space either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by Vinay might be wrong.  There are papers you pick up that are tied to unimportant quests that it will let you sell or destroy.  I think the only ones it won't let you destroy are main quest papers.  Whether or not you have to have them in your inventory or if all you have to do is read them to kick off the quest I couldn't say.  I think they have to be in your inventory.